# Delphi TRegEx bug?

Tags: regex, delphi

I try to validate the input `'3a'` for regex `'[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*'` with that source:

```
len := TRegEx.Create([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*).Match('3a').Length;
```

I expected `0` for `len` variable, but it was `2`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is not your real code. For a start it does not compile. You have omitted the quote marks. If we fix that then we have:

```
len := TRegEx.Create('[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*').Match('3a').Length;
```

But that returns a value of 1 and not 2 as you stated. This return value is correct because the `a` matches `[_a-zA-Z]` and then the input string ends.

I expect that you have the wrong regex. Perhaps you should be using

```
^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

The `^` matches the beginning of the input string, the `$` mathes the end. Presumably the input is taken from a source code tokenizer.

So the conclusion is that there is no bug evident in the Delphi regex code from this pattern and input.

Comment: Once I had a problem and thought "Hey, I can use Regular Expressions to solve that problem".  Then, I had two problems.